# Help with connecting electromagnet to dimmer

Tags: batteries, electromagnetism, physics, dimmer

I have an electromagnetic powered off a AA battery. Is there some kind of dimmer switch or similar item that would allow me to control the amount of power going to the electromagnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can control the amount of power going to your electromagnet by hooking a rheostat in series with the battery and electromagnet.

Of course you could buy a rheostat, but if your primary goal is to learn you can make one. Here is a nice tutorial explaining how [make a rheostat](http://www.energyquest.ca.gov/projects/rheostat.html). Just substitute your electromagnet for the light bulb shown.

Comment: Thanks - that looks like what I need ! Do you know of any good and fairly cheap ones that would work with a AA battery?

Comment: Robert: If you live near a Radio Shack you might try http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062299

Comment: Thanks! I do live near one and their site says it's in stock.